# When I tried to generate a table, I got this error "Undefined control sequence", how to fix it?

Tags: tables

This [post](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html) gives a convenient approach to generate Latex code and I am trying to reproduce that.

This is a piece of Python code,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
...                    'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
...                    'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})
>>> print(df.to_latex(index=False)) # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
```

which generated this Latex code

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
      name &    mask &    weapon \\
\midrule
   Raphael &     red &       sai \\
 Donatello &  purple &  bo staff \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

I compiled this code and got this table

[image]

and this error

```
Undefined control sequence

l.15 \toprule

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `\toprule` is defined in the booktabs package. Just include it in your document.

Comment: @AlainMerigot  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\toprule` (and `\midrule` or `\bottomrule`) are defined in the [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. It *must* be included before any use.

This package largely improves the visual appearance of tables by providing rules with varying width and by fixing some line spacing problems. Standard latex uses `\hline` to draw a rule between lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
      name &    mask &    weapon \\
\midrule
   Raphael &     red &       sai \\
 Donatello &  purple &  bo staff \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]